# Embed Google Docs Public Folder into webpage

Tags: google, embed

I have a user that wants to upload PDFs to a website whenever he wants. Of course adding it myself is too easy... he wants to have the ability to add and delete PDFs on demand.

I thought about embedding a public google doc folder into the webpage but I am starting to find dead ends. Does anyone know much about this or have a solution for this particular problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a CMS? since most have user permissions.

Comment: unfortunately I am not- wish I was in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way :

- Go to google Docs.
- Upload your PDF file to a public folder.
- Then click your file in document list.
- A preview will be opened.
- You will see a blue button named Open (right-bottom side)
- Click that button. You will be transferred docs.google.com
- Here you will see the top-menu like File, Edit...
- Choose File → Embed this PDF file. Then you can get an embed code.

The user would just have to add/edit/remove the embed code

source : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42097

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but not exactly what I was looking for.. . the user cannot touch any of the files. I don't trust them and nor do they trust themselves to. :)

Comment: It will be difficult to upload a file without having access to the said file.

Comment: Yes, I was looking more for a route where i could embed a "widget" similar to twitter but for a dropbox or google drive folder. But I have decided it does not exist.

Comment: So the user would have access to dropbox or google drive, upload his PDF file by himself, and automatically it would like display a link to this file on a website?
I think you can go to 
http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Dropbox_Addons
There you can find addons, php uploaders and folder viewers.
Maybe this is it.